# How to make table with Fix header ,Scrolling and column Resizalble

Tags: jquery, html, css

[Demo Works in IE only](http://jsfiddle.net/9qkp8/65/)

```
$(function ()
  {
      resolutionIndependentScroll(); 
      $("#tableList").colResizable({
            liveDrag: true,
            gripInnerHtml: "<div class='grip'></div>",
            draggingClass: "dragging"
      });
  });
```

I have to Fix header of scrolling and colResizalble table.

Comment: You may need to clarify exactly what you're after. Are you saying you want the header to remained fixed even when scrolling horizontally?

Comment: yes i need scrolling,coloumnResizing and fixed header of table....

Comment: Are you required to use [colResizable](http://quocity.com/colresizable/)? There are plenty of good alternatives here with the functionality you need: http://stackoverflow.com/q/983031/1085891

Answer (score 2):

@Means: Your requirements are 3 things: Fixed Header, Column Resizable and Scrolling. 
In adidtion, you can switch column order, hide/show columns as well. 
This example will satisfy all of them. 
We used your example in combination with Flexigrid. 
For some reasons, the link to jsFiddle is not working properly. So, please test it in local. 
You will need to download:

1. [flexigrid-1.1 package](http://code.google.com/p/flexigrid/downloads/detail?name=flexigrid-1.1.zip)
2. [jquery-1.5.2.min.js](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.2.min.js)

And extract them to `css` and `js` folder to use them locally like below:
**flexigrid.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>  
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/flexigrid.pack.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.5.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/flexigrid.pack.js"></script>
    <script> 
        $(document).ready(function() {  $('.tableList').flexigrid();});
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <table class="tableList" border="1">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th width="100" bgcolor="yellow">col1</th>
                <th width="100" bgcolor="yellow">col2</th>
                <th width="100" bgcolor="yellow">col3</th>
                <th width="100" bgcolor="yellow">col4</th>
                <th width="100" bgcolor="yellow">col5</th>
                <th width="100" bgcolor="yellow">col6</th>
                <th width="100" bgcolor="yellow">col7</th>
                <th width="100" bgcolor="yellow">col8</th>
                <th width="100" bgcolor="yellow">col9</th>
                <th width="100" bgcolor="yellow">col10</th>
                <th width="100" bgcolor="yellow">col11</th>
                <th width="100" bgcolor="yellow">col12</th>
                <th width="100" bgcolor="yellow">col13</th>
                <th width="100" bgcolor="yellow">col14</th>
                <th width="100" bgcolor="yellow">col15</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>value</td>
                <td>value</td>
                <td>value</td>
                <td>value</td>
                <td>value</td>
                <td>value</td>
                <td>value</td>
                <td>value</td>
                <td>value</td>
                <td>value</td>
                <td>value</td>
                <td>value</td>
                <td>value</td>
                <td>value</td>
                <td>value</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>value</td>
                <td>value</td>
                <td>value</td>
                <td>value</td>
                <td>value</td>
                <td>value</td>
                <td>value</td>
                <td>value</td>
                <td>value</td>
                <td>value</td>
                <td>value</td>
                <td>value</td>
                <td>value</td>
                <td>value</td>
                <td>value</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>value</td>
                <td>value</td>
                <td>value</td>
                <td>value</td>
                <td>value</td>
                <td>value</td>
                <td>value</td>
                <td>value</td>
                <td>value</td>
                <td>value</td>
                <td>value</td>
                <td>value</td>
                <td>value</td>
                <td>value</td>
                <td>value</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>value</td>
                <td>value</td>
                <td>value</td>
                <td>value</td>
                <td>value</td>
                <td>value</td>
                <td>value</td>
                <td>value</td>
                <td>value</td>
                <td>value</td>
                <td>value</td>
                <td>value</td>
                <td>value</td>
                <td>value</td>
                <td>value</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>value</td>
                <td>value</td>
                <td>value</td>
                <td>value</td>
                <td>value</td>
                <td>value</td>
                <td>value</td>
                <td>value</td>
                <td>value</td>
                <td>value</td>
                <td>value</td>
                <td>value</td>
                <td>value</td>
                <td>value</td>
                <td>value</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>value</td>
                <td>value</td>
                <td>value</td>
                <td>value</td>
                <td>value</td>
                <td>value</td>
                <td>value</td>
                <td>value</td>
                <td>value</td>
                <td>value</td>
                <td>value</td>
                <td>value</td>
                <td>value</td>
                <td>value</td>
                <td>value</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>value</td>
                <td>value</td>
                <td>value</td>
                <td>value</td>
                <td>value</td>
                <td>value</td>
                <td>value</td>
                <td>value</td>
                <td>value</td>
                <td>value</td>
                <td>value</td>
                <td>value</td>
                <td>value</td>
                <td>value</td>
                <td>value</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>value</td>
                <td>value</td>
                <td>value</td>
                <td>value</td>
                <td>value</td>
                <td>value</td>
                <td>value</td>
                <td>value</td>
                <td>value</td>
                <td>value</td>
                <td>value</td>
                <td>value</td>
                <td>value</td>
                <td>value</td>
                <td>value</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>value</td>
                <td>value</td>
                <td>value</td>
                <td>value</td>
                <td>value</td>
                <td>value</td>
                <td>value</td>
                <td>value</td>
                <td>value</td>
                <td>value</td>
                <td>value</td>
                <td>value</td>
                <td>value</td>
                <td>value</td>
                <td>value</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>value</td>
                <td>value</td>
                <td>value</td>
                <td>value</td>
                <td>value</td>
                <td>value</td>
                <td>value</td>
                <td>value</td>
                <td>value</td>
                <td>value</td>
                <td>value</td>
                <td>value</td>
                <td>value</td>
                <td>value</td>
                <td>value</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>value</td>
                <td>value</td>
                <td>value</td>
                <td>value</td>
                <td>value</td>
                <td>value</td>
                <td>value</td>
                <td>value</td>
                <td>value</td>
                <td>value</td>
                <td>value</td>
                <td>value</td>
                <td>value</td>
                <td>value</td>
                <td>value</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>value</td>
                <td>value</td>
                <td>value</td>
                <td>value</td>
                <td>value</td>
                <td>value</td>
                <td>value</td>
                <td>value</td>
                <td>value</td>
                <td>value</td>
                <td>value</td>
                <td>value</td>
                <td>value</td>
                <td>value</td>
                <td>value</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>value</td>
                <td>value</td>
                <td>value</td>
                <td>value</td>
                <td>value</td>
                <td>value</td>
                <td>value</td>
                <td>value</td>
                <td>value</td>
                <td>value</td>
                <td>value</td>
                <td>value</td>
                <td>value</td>
                <td>value</td>
                <td>value</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>value</td>
                <td>value</td>
                <td>value</td>
                <td>value</td>
                <td>value</td>
                <td>value</td>
                <td>value</td>
                <td>value</td>
                <td>value</td>
                <td>value</td>
                <td>value</td>
                <td>value</td>
                <td>value</td>
                <td>value</td>
                <td>value</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

I hope it's helpful.
Any comments will be welcome. Thanks.

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't work at all. It results in 403 "Forbidden" errors on both of the `css` files, as well as the `flexigrid.pack.js` file.

Comment: @TroyAlford : Thanks Troy, I have updated new link please check. It runs on Firefox 19.0.2 when I tested. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u99zX/11)

Comment: I still get 403's for the `flexigrid js` files. I am also using Firefox 19.0.2. As a result I can't resize any of the columns at all.

Comment: @sarcastyx: Thanks for your feedback. I'd better post original codes as an answer.

Comment: To ALL: I have updated the answer, please check. It works for both IE and FF.

Comment: @TroyAlford: check and let me know if you have any question

Comment: @sarcastyx: check and let me know if you have any question

Comment: @Means: try it and let me know if you have any question

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of plugins out there.. but my choice is [jQgrid](http://www.trirand.com/blog/).

It is a plugin with lot of features and options. They also support fixed header, fixed column and also column resizing >> http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html << Try Advanced -> Resiziing.

It is one of the up-to-date plugin out there, so give it a try and let us know.

Answer (score 1):

for minimal requirement, you can use [**DataTable.js**](http://www.datatables.net/index)

please find custom live demo as per your requirement [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/W5zuy/).

**HTML**

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display" id="example">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Rendering engine</th>
            <th>Browser</th>
            <th>Platform(s)</th>
            <th>Engine version</th>
            <th>CSS grade</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="odd gradeX">
            <td>Trident</td>
            <td>Internet
                 Explorer 4.0</td>
            <td>Win 95+</td>
            <td class="center">4</td>
            <td class="center">X</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="odd gradeC">
            <td>Trident</td>
            <td>Internet
                 Explorer 5.0</td>
            <td>Win 95+</td>
            <td class="center">5</td>
            <td class="center">C</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="odd gradeA">
            <td>Trident</td>
            <td>Internet
                 Explorer 5.5</td>
            <td>Win 95+</td>
            <td class="center">5.5</td>
            <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="odd gradeA">
            <td>Trident</td>
            <td>Internet
                 Explorer 6</td>
            <td>Win 98+</td>
            <td class="center">6</td>
            <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="odd gradeA">
            <td>Trident</td>
            <td>Internet Explorer 7</td>
            <td>Win XP SP2+</td>
            <td class="center">7</td>
            <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="odd gradeA">
            <td>Trident</td>
            <td>AOL browser (AOL desktop)</td>
            <td>Win XP</td>
            <td class="center">6</td>
            <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA">
            <td>Gecko</td>
            <td>Firefox 1.0</td>
            <td>Win 98+ / OSX.2+</td>
            <td class="center">1.7</td>
            <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA">
            <td>Gecko</td>
            <td>Firefox 1.5</td>
            <td>Win 98+ / OSX.2+</td>
            <td class="center">1.8</td>
            <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA">
            <td>Gecko</td>
            <td>Firefox 2.0</td>
            <td>Win 98+ / OSX.2+</td>
            <td class="center">1.8</td>
            <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA">
            <td>Gecko</td>
            <td>Firefox 3.0</td>
            <td>Win 2k+ / OSX.3+</td>
            <td class="center">1.9</td>
            <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA">
            <td>Gecko</td>
            <td>Camino 1.0</td>
            <td>OSX.2+</td>
            <td class="center">1.8</td>
            <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA">
            <td>Gecko</td>
            <td>Camino 1.5</td>
            <td>OSX.3+</td>
            <td class="center">1.8</td>
            <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA">
            <td>Gecko</td>
            <td>Netscape 7.2</td>
            <td>Win 95+ / Mac OS 8.6-9.2</td>
            <td class="center">1.7</td>
            <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA">
            <td>Gecko</td>
            <td>Netscape Browser 8</td>
            <td>Win 98SE+</td>
            <td class="center">1.7</td>
            <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA">
            <td>Gecko</td>
            <td>Netscape Navigator 9</td>
            <td>Win 98+ / OSX.2+</td>
            <td class="center">1.8</td>
            <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA">
            <td>Gecko</td>
            <td>Mozilla 1.0</td>
            <td>Win 95+ / OSX.1+</td>
            <td class="center">1</td>
            <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA">
            <td>Gecko</td>
            <td>Mozilla 1.1</td>
            <td>Win 95+ / OSX.1+</td>
            <td class="center">1.1</td>
            <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA">
            <td>Gecko</td>
            <td>Mozilla 1.2</td>
            <td>Win 95+ / OSX.1+</td>
            <td class="center">1.2</td>
            <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA">
            <td>Gecko</td>
            <td>Mozilla 1.3</td>
            <td>Win 95+ / OSX.1+</td>
            <td class="center">1.3</td>
            <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA">
            <td>Gecko</td>
            <td>Mozilla 1.4</td>
            <td>Win 95+ / OSX.1+</td>
            <td class="center">1.4</td>
            <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA">
            <td>Gecko</td>
            <td>Mozilla 1.5</td>
            <td>Win 95+ / OSX.1+</td>
            <td class="center">1.5</td>
            <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA">
            <td>Gecko</td>
            <td>Mozilla 1.6</td>
            <td>Win 95+ / OSX.1+</td>
            <td class="center">1.6</td>
            <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA">
            <td>Gecko</td>
            <td>Mozilla 1.7</td>
            <td>Win 98+ / OSX.1+</td>
            <td class="center">1.7</td>
            <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA">
            <td>Gecko</td>
            <td>Mozilla 1.8</td>
            <td>Win 98+ / OSX.1+</td>
            <td class="center">1.8</td>
            <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA">
            <td>Gecko</td>
            <td>Seamonkey 1.1</td>
            <td>Win 98+ / OSX.2+</td>
            <td class="center">1.8</td>
            <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA">
            <td>Gecko</td>
            <td>Epiphany 2.20</td>
            <td>Gnome</td>
            <td class="center">1.8</td>
            <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA">
            <td>Webkit</td>
            <td>Safari 1.2</td>
            <td>OSX.3</td>
            <td class="center">125.5</td>
            <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA">
            <td>Webkit</td>
            <td>Safari 1.3</td>
            <td>OSX.3</td>
            <td class="center">312.8</td>
            <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA">
            <td>Webkit</td>
            <td>Safari 2.0</td>
            <td>OSX.4+</td>
            <td class="center">419.3</td>
            <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA">
            <td>Webkit</td>
            <td>Safari 3.0</td>
            <td>OSX.4+</td>
            <td class="center">522.1</td>
            <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA">
            <td>Webkit</td>
            <td>OmniWeb 5.5</td>
            <td>OSX.4+</td>
            <td class="center">420</td>
            <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA">
            <td>Webkit</td>
            <td>iPod Touch / iPhone</td>
            <td>iPod</td>
            <td class="center">420.1</td>
            <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA">
            <td>Webkit</td>
            <td>S60</td>
            <td>S60</td>
            <td class="center">413</td>
            <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA">
            <td>Presto</td>
            <td>Opera 7.0</td>
            <td>Win 95+ / OSX.1+</td>
            <td class="center">-</td>
            <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA">
            <td>Presto</td>
            <td>Opera 7.5</td>
            <td>Win 95+ / OSX.2+</td>
            <td class="center">-</td>
            <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA">
            <td>Presto</td>
            <td>Opera 8.0</td>
            <td>Win 95+ / OSX.2+</td>
            <td class="center">-</td>
            <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA">
            <td>Presto</td>
            <td>Opera 8.5</td>
            <td>Win 95+ / OSX.2+</td>
            <td class="center">-</td>
            <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA">
            <td>Presto</td>
            <td>Opera 9.0</td>
            <td>Win 95+ / OSX.3+</td>
            <td class="center">-</td>
            <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA">
            <td>Presto</td>
            <td>Opera 9.2</td>
            <td>Win 88+ / OSX.3+</td>
            <td class="center">-</td>
            <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA">
            <td>Presto</td>
            <td>Opera 9.5</td>
            <td>Win 88+ / OSX.3+</td>
            <td class="center">-</td>
            <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA">
            <td>Presto</td>
            <td>Opera for Wii</td>
            <td>Wii</td>
            <td class="center">-</td>
            <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA">
            <td>Presto</td>
            <td>Nokia N800</td>
            <td>N800</td>
            <td class="center">-</td>
            <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA">
            <td>Presto</td>
            <td>Nintendo DS browser</td>
            <td>Nintendo DS</td>
            <td class="center">8.5</td>
            <td class="center">C/A<sup>1</sup></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeC">
            <td>KHTML</td>
            <td>Konqureror 3.1</td>
            <td>KDE 3.1</td>
            <td class="center">3.1</td>
            <td class="center">C</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA">
            <td>KHTML</td>
            <td>Konqureror 3.3</td>
            <td>KDE 3.3</td>
            <td class="center">3.3</td>
            <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA">
            <td>KHTML</td>
            <td>Konqureror 3.5</td>
            <td>KDE 3.5</td>
            <td class="center">3.5</td>
            <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeX">
            <td>Tasman</td>
            <td>Internet Explorer 4.5</td>
            <td>Mac OS 8-9</td>
            <td class="center">-</td>
            <td class="center">X</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeC">
            <td>Tasman</td>
            <td>Internet Explorer 5.1</td>
            <td>Mac OS 7.6-9</td>
            <td class="center">1</td>
            <td class="center">C</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeC">
            <td>Tasman</td>
            <td>Internet Explorer 5.2</td>
            <td>Mac OS 8-X</td>
            <td class="center">1</td>
            <td class="center">C</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA">
            <td>Misc</td>
            <td>NetFront 3.1</td>
            <td>Embedded devices</td>
            <td class="center">-</td>
            <td class="center">C</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA">
            <td>Misc</td>
            <td>NetFront 3.4</td>
            <td>Embedded devices</td>
            <td class="center">-</td>
            <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeX">
            <td>Misc</td>
            <td>Dillo 0.8</td>
            <td>Embedded devices</td>
            <td class="center">-</td>
            <td class="center">X</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeX">
            <td>Misc</td>
            <td>Links</td>
            <td>Text only</td>
            <td class="center">-</td>
            <td class="center">X</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeX">
            <td>Misc</td>
            <td>Lynx</td>
            <td>Text only</td>
            <td class="center">-</td>
            <td class="center">X</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeC">
            <td>Misc</td>
            <td>IE Mobile</td>
            <td>Windows Mobile 6</td>
            <td class="center">-</td>
            <td class="center">C</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeC">
            <td>Misc</td>
            <td>PSP browser</td>
            <td>PSP</td>
            <td class="center">-</td>
            <td class="center">C</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeU">
            <td>Other browsers</td>
            <td>All others</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td class="center">-</td>
            <td class="center">U</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $('#example').dataTable( {
        "sDom": "Rlfrtip",
        "sScrollY": "200px",
        "bPaginate": false
    });
});
```

**------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------**

for more complex Grid features you can use this simple [**jqGrid**](http://www.trirand.com/blog/).

custom demo for jqGrid is [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/Hcuj3/2/).

**HTML**

```
<table id="grid"></table>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var data = [[1, "Arcenal", "Barca"], 
            [2, "ManU", "Chelcea"],  
            [3, "RM", "Chelcea"],  
            [4, "ManU", "Arcenal"],  
            [5, "ManCity", "Chelcea"],  
            [6, "ManU", "ManCity"],  
            [7, "ManCity", "LiverPool"],  
            [8, "LiverPool", "Barca"], 
            [9, "RM", "Barca"],
            [10, "Chelcea", "LiverPool"]];

$("#grid").jqGrid({
    datatype: "local",
    height: 100,
    colNames: ['Match_no', 'Team1', 'Team2'],
    colModel: [{
        name: 'Match_no',
        index: 'Match_no',
        width: 60,
        sorttype: "int"},
    {
        name: 'Team1',
        index: 'Team1',
        width: 90,
        sorttype: "string"},
    {
        name: 'Team2',
        index: 'Team2',
        width: 90,
        sorttype: "string"}
    ],
    caption: "jqGrid sample demo",
});

var names = ["Match_no", "Team1", "Team2"];
var mydata = [];

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    mydata[i] = {};
    for (var j = 0; j < data[i].length; j++) {
        mydata[i][names[j]] = data[i][j];
    }
}

for (var i = 0; i <= mydata.length; i++) {
    $("#grid").jqGrid('addRowData', i + 1, mydata[i]);
}
```